# Change Text Object Value of Crystal Report Dynamically in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, parameters, crystal-reports

I have this picture of my current format of crystal report.
[image]

My problem is, I want to set the value of `fullName` field dynamically depending on the query result of my vb.net form. For example, I have this code from my vb form,

```
sql = "SELECT fullName FROM tblClient WHERE clientID = '" & ST-TAC-23 & "'"
da = new SqlDataAdapter (sql, con)
dt = new DataTable
da.fill(dt)
```

I want the `dt` value to be passed on `fullName` object in my crystal report. For example the `dt` value is Mark Zucker, I want the `fullName` field in my cr to display Mark Zucker also. How could possibly do that?

Answer (score 2):

I have found out the best trick for this problem. This is how I fixed it.

In the `load` event of the form (form for crystal report viewer), I coded this lines,

```
Dim fName As TextObject
fName = rptDoc.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("crFullName")
' display the value for the report
fName.Text = frmAccInventory.lblName.Text
```

Where "crFullName" is the name of the `text object` in crystal report. `rptDoc` is declared at frmAccInventory as new crystalReport1 (name of the crystal report file)

credits to Mikaykay of http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/daa7e60d-a444-449d-9ac2-a57415217bbc/

Comment: don't forget to import CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
and CrystalDecisions.Shared